# Correctness of a proof for Hodges' estimator

Tags: estimation, convergence, asymptotics, sequence-analysis, efficiency

We know the following is Hodges' estimator:
$$
\delta_n = 
\begin{cases}
\bar{X}_n & |X_n| \geq n^{-1/4} \\ 
a\bar{X}_n & |X_n| < n^{-1/4} \\ 
\end{cases}
$$
where $X_1, ..., X_n \sim N(\theta, 1)$, and $a \in [0,1)$.

We want to show that for $a=0$ and $\theta = 0$, $n^\alpha(\delta_n-\theta) \rightarrow_p 0$ for some $\alpha > 0$.

(**) Side question: can we say that $a_n(\delta_n-\theta) \rightarrow_p 0$ for some $\alpha > 0$, and any arbitrary sequence $a_n$ such that $a_n> 0$ for any $n$, and $a=0$ and $\theta = 0$.

Here I provide my proof. Could you check if it is completely correct? 
Given the definition of the convergence in probability we want to show that $\mathbb{P}(|n^\alpha \delta_n| > \epsilon ) \rightarrow 0$, as $n \rightarrow +\infty$, for some $\epsilon > 0$. We have: 
$$
\mathbb{P}( |n^\alpha \delta_n| > \epsilon ) = \mathbb{P}( |n^\alpha \bar{X}_n| > \epsilon   | \quad |\bar{X}_n| \geq n^{-1/4}  ) \mathbb{P}( |\bar{X}_n| \geq n^{-1/4} ) + \mathbb{P}( a|n^\alpha \bar{X}_n| > \epsilon   | \quad |\bar{X}_n| < n^{-1/4}  ) \mathbb{P}( |\bar{X}_n| < n^{-1/4} )
$$
Since $a=0$, then $\mathbb{P}( a|n^\alpha \bar{X}_n| > \epsilon   | \quad |\bar{X}_n| < n^{-1/4}  ) = 0$. 
Also we can show that $\mathbb{P}( |\bar{X}_n| \geq n^{-1/4} )$ for big enough $n$, when $\theta=0$, which gives us $\mathbb{P}( |n^\alpha \delta_n| > \epsilon ) =0$ as $n$ grows to infinity.

One double that I have about this proof is that, with the same procedure we can prove that $a_n (\delta_n) \rightarrow_p0$ for any $a_n>0$ (as mentioned in statement (**) but I highly doubt that the statement is true).

Comment: Should there be a bar over the $X_n$ in the definition of Hodge's estimator?  As it stands, the definition makes no sense to me.  Wikipedia seems to agree with me.

Comment: Ah yes. Thanks for pointing it out. I am correcting it.

Comment: Attributed to Joseph Hodges, so Hodges' and Hodges's would be OK, but not Hodge's.